# Tkinter: Trying to create Checkbuttons in a loop over the keys of a dictionary

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I want to create a GUI with tkinter, where you can select the keys of a dictionary of any size using Checkbuttons. The dictionary stores text paragraphs. At the end the selected text paragraphs should be output as a text file. Unfortunately my code does not work. Thanks for your help!

This is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

text_dict: dict = {
    "key_1": "text paragraph 1...",
    "key_2": "text paragraph 2...",
    "key_3": "text paragraph 3..."
}

keys_list: list = list(text_dict.keys())
selected_keys_dict: dict = {key: 0 for key in text_dict}

window = tk.Tk()


def call_back():
    selected_keys_dict[box] = var.get()


var_list = [tk.IntVar() for item in keys_list]
for index, box in enumerate(keys_list):
    var = var_list[index]
    tk.Checkbutton(window, text=box, variable=var, height=2, width=30, command=call_back).pack()
    selected_keys_dict[box] = var.get()


def get_checked_boxes():
    output = []
    for key in selected_keys_dict:
        if selected_keys_dict[key] == 1:
            output.append(text_dict[key])
    with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
        for paragraph in output:
            f.write(paragraph + "\n")


tk.Button(window, text='Print checked Checkboxes', command=get_checked_boxes).pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to provide a better description of the problem than "does not work" for us to have any idea of what to look for.  What went wrong?  What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: You populate the `selected_keys_dict` dictionary just after you create each `Checkbutton` so the user hasn't had the time to input any data in yet. Please look at some `tkinter` tutorials or [event driven programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming). To solve this make `selected_keys_dict` into a dictionary of `str` to `tk.IntVar` instead of `str` to `int`

Comment: @TheLizzard 

Thanks for the answer! It helps me a lot :-). Now the program outputs "textparagraph 3..." when the last checkbox (with "key_3") is selected. Unfortunately, it has no effect when you select the previous checkboxes ("key_1" and "key_2"). I don't really understand, shouldn't it be stored in the dictionary "selected_keys_dict" whether they are selected or not?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Note that `selected_keys_dict[box]` is updated inside `call_back()`, so what is the value of `box` when it is updated?

Answer (score 0):

When you are clicking a Checkbutton you are calling the `call_back` function which uses the `box` and `var` variables. Those variables are the remaining of the `for loop` that created all the `Checkbutton`s and they contain value from the last iteration of the loop.

- `var` will be `var_list[2]`
- `box` will be `'key_3'`

You need to pass the corresponding `var` and `box` with each  `call_back` call.

You can do it using `lambda` function like so:

```py
    tk.Checkbutton(window, text=box, variable=var, height=2, width=30, command=lambda b=box, v=var : call_back(b, v)).pack()
```

And then you should also fix you `call_back` function to tack those two arguments:

```py
def call_back(box_, var_):
    selected_keys_dict[box_] = var_.get()
```